Is there a way to change a vertex color and it updates the color on all the objects vertices connected to it?
I am beginner in blender and still learning. And I want to make a city with different colors and shape of buildings. Shape is possible through geomtery nodes. Colors is also possible by changes the hues and saturation. But I would like to edit colors of the already assigned vertex colors for some buildings, and I also know the manual way to selecting vertices by the materials assigned to them and changing it manually. But that would take ton of my time. I just wanna know if there is any kind of modular way to it? or a faster or any kind of addon you would suggest?

